# postgresql - null value error on function

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to resolve this `ERROR: null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier` when trying to select my function:

```
select * from store_keys();
ERROR:  null values cannot be formatted as an SQL identifier
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT string_agg(
    format('SELECT %1$I, count(email_store_key), email_store_key, form_created_datetime
            FROM %1$I where email_store_key=0 GROUP BY 3, 4', tbl_name),
    ' UNION ')            FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_schema = 'abc_dev_sch_1234'
    AND table_name LIKE 'fact_%'"
```

The base query it uses, does not produce `null values`. So where is this coming from??

```
select count(email_store_key), email_store_key, form_created_datetime
FROM <table_name> where email_store_key=0 GROUP BY email_store_key, form_created_datetime;
```

Here's my create statement:

```
DROP FUNCTION store_keys();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION store_keys()
RETURNS TABLE (tbl_name varchar, count_keys bigint, email_store_key integer, form_created_datetime timestamp)
AS $$
DECLARE
  qry text;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(
    format('SELECT %1$I, count(email_store_key), email_store_key, form_created_datetime
            FROM %1$I where email_store_key=0 GROUP BY 3, 4', tbl_name),
    ' UNION ') INTO qry
  FROM information_schema.tables
  WHERE table_schema = 'abc_dev_sch_1234'
    AND table_name LIKE 'fact_%';

  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE qry;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Simple typo, I think. Your `format` call is using the output variable `tbl_name` instead of the column `table_name`. By the way, I think your first format specifier will need to be `%1$L` rather than `%1$I`.

Comment: @NickBarnes The only significant difference between %I and %L in this context is that the former is double-quoted if necessary; both produce a string value. The error arises from the fact that %I does not accept a NULL value, which is passed in from the uninitialized "tbl_name" output parameter. Simple typo, indeed.

Comment: @Patrick: `%L` produces a single-quoted value, like `quote_literal()`